# Accessing object's properties like if the objects were arrays

Tags: php, zend-framework

Is it possible to access object's properties, when you don't know just how their names will be written?

My problem is that when a query returns Zend_Db_Table_Rowset_Abstract object, there are some fields with names like  "name_fr", "name_en", "name_au". I want to access either of them according to the current language used in the application. To achieve this I write the code   this way:

```
$result = $myModel->fetchAll($query)->current();
$row = $result->toArray();
echo 'Your name is '.$row['name_'.$language];
```

This is very annoying. Is it possible to write a code like this for example:

```
$result = $myModel->fetchAll($query)->current();
echo 'Your name is '.$result->name_{$language};
```

Comment: You can hide this logic in a custom row class: http://pastebin.com/ny6JtF5b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
$result = $myModel->fetchAll($query)->current();
echo 'Your name is '.$result->{'name_'.$language};
```

Comment: Cheers Godwin! It is working!  Please would you tell me where this behavior is documented. How can I search for it? Does it have a name? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Fairly sure it's usually called a dynamic property but I can't find any official documentation out there (although I'm sure it is).

Comment: It's called variable variables: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 1):

When you use `Zend_Db_Table` and `fetchAll()->current()`, type of returned object is `Zend_Db_Table_Row`, which inherits from `Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract`.  `Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract` implements `ArrayAccess`([manual](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php)) interface, which means you can refer to object properties using array key notation.

So, syntax:

```
'Your name is '.$row['name_'.$language];
```

should work without using `toArray()`;

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$result->{"name_$language"}
```