# php appending string to stdClass object

Tags: php, concatenation, stdclass

I'm pulling records from database, and I have a filed called `content_fr`
the `_fr` is being dynamicaly created based on a site language.

Getting all records from the table gives me of course `content_fr` field. What I need to do is manually assign the suffix in this `case _fr` if I try to concatenate `$row->content.'_fr'` I get the error `Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$content`, which makes sense since $content does not exist, but `$content_fr` does. Using standard arrays I was able to do it like `$row['content_fr']`, and worked fine, but now using stdClass I'm getting an error.

How can I convert `$row->content.'_fr'` into one string, so that php sees it as `$row->content_fr` ?

Comment: Dunno how your models are set, but you should use getters for columns and there you would implement the localization-to-column logic (injecting the language into the model, ofc).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try it like this :

```
$row -> {'content_' . $language}; // assuming $language = 'fr'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as follows:

```
$row->{'content_fr'};
```

EDIT: By the way, this question has been asked here many times. See previous threads such as this one: [Accessing object's properties like if the objects were arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238380/accessing-objects-properties-like-if-the-objects-were-arrays/8238406).

Comment: When downvoting, please leave a comment.

Comment: $row->{'content_fr'} makes no sense as it is the same as $row->content_fr. The problem is the concatenation of strings into one property name. @Tom van der Woerdt 's solutions is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: I +1'd your answer cause it is what he needs, not sure why someone downvoted again.

Comment: @markus, It's quite different, I'm showing that the OP can access the property using a string value.

Comment: @drew010 No, it's not what he needs. What he needs is Toms answer, as stated above.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$lang = 'fr';
$property = 'content_' . $lang; // content_fr
$row->$property = 'something';
```

Comment: Yes the most I've ever written!

Comment: This is also a good alternative way to do this. Why do people keep downvoting when the answer is valid but perhaps just not the full code the OP needs?